# Female jack for AC/DC power supply

Tags: pcb-design, connector, power-connector

I cannot find a female jack to connect the terminal of an AC/DC [power supply](https://slpower.com/data/collateral/TE150_Datasheet.pdf). My idea was to bring the transformed power from the AC/DC power supply and connect their terminal to the PCB via a jack or connector. I found two different terminals. One is KPP-4P and the second is 6-pin Molex (as the picture below shows). The female connector suitable for KPP-4P can withstand up to 7.5A ([MW DIO-BU4](https://www.reichelt.com/ch/en/power-din-panel-jack-4-pin-mw-dio-bu4-p162282.html?&trstct=pol_0&nbc=1)). In my case, the AC/DC power supply I chose can generate 12V at 12.5A. Therefore, the female jacks I have found so far are not suitable. For the 6-pin Molex terminal, I could not find a suitable one.

Any advice? It does exist other options?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: The female counterpart to the male plug on the supply output must exist and should be suitable for 12.5A if the supply was designed properly. Try digging through the Molex website a bit more. I know it can be confusing.

Comment: the Molex webpage for that component has a "mates with" section

Comment: They have compatible mates but they are not suitable.... They cannot withstand high current....

Answer (score 2):

I contacted Kycon about this a while back, that 7.5A on their data sheet is per pin. ( That makes it 15 Amp capable with 2 positive and 2 negative )

It is a little miss leading so I contacted them directly and that was their response.

Hope this helps others that are in the same position as I was.

Comment: Edit your answer to highlight the response from Kycon, by for example, putting quotation marks around it, and to further emphasize it, **their response was:**